# getURL throws error; same URL works in browser. OR: How to cleanup after getURL()

Tags: r, curl, asynchronous, rcurl, geturl

#### summary:

```
## parameters_string is a vector, 3K long, of different parameter values to the API
U <- paste0("www.Somehost.com/api?", parameters_string)
```

- `getURL(U)` eventually fails, after around 350 calls. Continues to work after restarting R
- `getURL(U, async=FALSE)` Works without error. Other than it is of course very slow.

#### Details:

I am hitting an API, iterating over several thousand urls
The API has a counter indicating how many calls can still be made and I am beneath the limit.

The problem is that after some time, `getURL()` fails, throwing an `"Could not resolve host: Somehost.com` error.

I can access the url via any browser. Also, restarting R resolves the problem, as does setting the `async=FALSE` flag in `getURL`

I've tried `closeAllConnections()` but this did not help.

**What is the best way to intermittently clean up whatever `getURL()` is leaving open so that it can be used with `async=TRUE` ?**

Comment: have a look at the development version of the curl package